# Is it possibe to have a GIF or video in Google DialogFlow chatbot as a response

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

How to Keep video or Gif in the response of Google dialogflow es chatbot.

Comment: What are you using as the chatbot client?  Think about Dialogflow as knowing "what to respond with" and not "how to mechanically respond to the user".  There are a variety of clients/plugins/code that one can include in a web page or android/iOS.  Knowing which one you are using will help us a lot.   For example ... https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.